# Python: dictionary comparisons in splitting lists by first character

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, comparison

Here is the exercise that is stumping me:

Implement function `partition()` that splits a list of soccer players into two groups. More precisely, it takes a list of first names (strings) as input and prints the names of those soccer players whose first name starts with a letter between and including A and M.

```
>>>partition([''Eleanor'', ''Evelyn'', ''Sammy'', ''Owen'', ''Gavin''])
Eleanor
Evelyn
Gavin
>>>partition([''Xena'', ''Sammy'', ''Gavin''])
>>>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def partition():
    names=[''Eleanor'', ''Evenlyn'', ''Sammy'', ''Owen'', ''Gavin'']
    for name in names:
        if name[0]==''ABCDEFGHIJKLM'':
            print (name)
```

I know I'm going wrong in defining the letters, but I'm hitting a blank, especially because my professor suggested that I use dictionary comparisons. Is there a way to use comparisons to split the names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
name[0] in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
```

will tell you if a character appears in the string.

```
name[0] == 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
```

compares the single letter to the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You could import `string` and use the pre-defined set of uppercase ASCII characters, rather than having to do it yourself:

```
import string
letters_a_to_m = string.ascii_uppercase[:13]
#'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'

if name[0] in letters_a_to_m:
    print(name)
```